# I can't connect a html button with database using C#?

Tags: c#, html, css, webforms

I am new to c# and .NET. I converted a bootstrap=theme in asp.net and trying to add functionality on bellow button i.e. connection to database/any-other function call in asp.net etc. plz help!

```
<div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." />
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button type='submit' name='search' id='search-btn' class="btn btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                            </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this markup within a `<form>` tag? Have you done any research/walkthroughs/tutorials? I think it would be difficult to NOT find examples of button events for webforms.

Answer (score 1):

you have two option .

1. convert your button and text box into asp control and add css class.
   e.g:
    `<asp:button id="btnsave" cssClass="btn btn-flat" Text="Submit" />`
2. And other is using ajax  and web method you fetch data from database